# How to locate the properties file in the spring context configuration file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring web mvc project, and I put all the spring related files under `WEB-INF\spring`, including a `ormlite.xml` and a `jdbc.properties`.

Now I want to locate the `jdbc.properties` file in the `ormlite.xml`,[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9L5H.png):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"/>
```

But when I run the application ,it will told me that :

`Could not load properties`

It can not find the properties file.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Spring forum:

> The problem is that /WEB-INF isn't accessible as it isn't in the root
>   of the path, you must use the same path as you use in your test case
>   (include the src/main/webapp part but that will break your application
>   from running).
>
> I suggest you move the jdbc.properties to the src/main/resources
>   directory and simply use classpath: prefix to load the properties.
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
> ```
>
> The code above assumes they are on the root of the classpath (which is
>   where they are when they are in `src/main/resources`).

I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - property files outside the classpath.

My solution:

First define a properties bean:

```
<bean id="configProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/your.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Then reference it in the property-placeholder:

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="configProperties" />
```

Works perfectly well for me!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"/>
```

Use:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"/>
```

And your properties will be available in Spring file, and don't forget to add a namespace: `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"`

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: That's strange, I am using it the same like you and it is working for me just fine. The only difference I can see that you are using 2.5 version in your schema location. Change it from: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd` to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd` and try again.

Comment: I changed to 3.0, but it does not work. And I  notice this:`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist` It say the `class path resource`, but my `jdbc.properties` is not inside the class path directory.

Comment: Do you have a `ContextLoaderListener` declared in your `web.xml`? Not exactly sure why it's trying to load it from the classpath. If you add `file:` prefix? Would it makes any difference, like that: p:location="file:/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"/?

Comment: Like that: p:location="file:WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"

Comment: Yes, I declare a `ContextLoaderListener ` in the web.xml.  But I am now doing the junit test using SpringJunit. So I think this have nothing to do with the web.xml. And I have tried to add the `file:` prefix, it still does noto work.

Comment: Both `p:location="file:WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"` and `p:location="file:/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the prefix to instruct Spring how to attempt to load the properties. I think your definition needs to be:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"/>
```

Note the addition of the ***file:*** prefix.

Comment: Have you tried file:WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties? i.e. missing out the beginning slash?

Comment: And you've tried: <context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"/> ? Again notice the missing first slash?

Comment: OK just noticed that you said you are using Spring 3.2.3 release. As of 3.1.0 Spring switched support over to PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer from PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer. However as you're running with the 3.0 namespace declaration we won't be loading that. So can you please try <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties"/> with your namespace declared as http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.  http://i.imgur.com/z3Kv2gC.png.  I am going crazy....